# CiviCRM isn't recognising CSV files as CSV files

Tags: csv

How do I fix this? It's urgent!

When I try to upload a CSV file, CiviCRM does not recognize it as such.

Comment: can you give some more information about the problem? 
what do you mean by "does not recognize it as such"?
are you trying to import contacts? contributions?

Comment: It might help if you post a link to the CSV file in question.

Answer (score 3):

CSV files aren't a single common format.  For instance, in the US, fields are often separated by commas, but in Europe, often by semicommas.  If you're importing, there should be an "import field separator" option (see screenshot).

Ultimately, there's not enough information in your question to help you.  Others have made suggestions as to how to better ask the question to get better help.  I hope you report back with the solution if you find it!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some options to consider

- sometimes if you save a csv in eg LibreOffice and then edit it again and resave it can be rejected by civicrm, in which case simply try opening your csv, copy all cells in to a new csv, then save and do not re-edit that file or try the below method
- sometimes an Excel generated csv can be a problem, in which case perhaps try loading as a Google sheet, then downloading a csv from there